# Random "404 Not Found" error on PasrseObject SaveAsynch (on Unity/Win)

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I started using Parse on Unity for a windows desktop game.

I save very simple objects in a very simple way.
Unfortunately, 10% of the time, i randomly get a 404 error on the SaveAsynch method :-(
This happen on different kind of ParseObject.
I also isolated the run context to avoid any external interference.
I checked the object id when this error happen and everything looks ok. 
The strange thing is that 90% of the time, i save these objects without an error (during the same application run).

Did someone already got this problem ?

Just in case, here is my code (but there is nothing special i think):

```
{
    encodedContent = Convert.ToBase64String(ZipHelper.CompressString(jsonDocument));
    mLoadedParseObject[key]["encodedContent "] = encodedContent ;
    mLoadedParseObject[key].SaveAsync().ContinueWith(OnTaskEnd);
}


....


void OnTaskEnd(Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        OnTaskError(task);                          // print error ....
    else
        mState = States.SUCEEDED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void DoTest()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoTestAsync());
    }

    private IEnumerator DoTestAsync()
    {
        yield return 1;

        Terminal.Log("Starting 404 Test");


        var obj = new ParseObject("Test1");

        obj["encodedContent"] = "Hello World";

        Terminal.Log("Saving");
        obj.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(OnTaskEnd);
    }

    private void OnTaskEnd(Task task)
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
            Terminal.LogError(task.Exception.Message);
        else
            Terminal.LogSuccess("Thank You !");
    }
```

Was not able to replicate. I got a Thank You. Could you try updating your Parse SDK.

**EDIT**

404 could be due to a bad username / password match. The exception messages are not the best.